# regex, match string which contains linebreak with lookaroud str_replace in R

Tags: regex, r, regex-lookarounds

I'm using str_replace function in the stringr package in R. I want to replace substring between PARTITIONED BY and STORED AS

Those commands work

```
my_string="esrhjg erguhg rziughrtPARTITIONED BY hzueirghf zreeuifh iuehg reuhg riutghSTORED ASiugh oer hfz"
p="(?<=PARTITIONED BY).*(?=STORED AS)"
str_replace(my_string,p,"TO REPLACE")
```

Those cammands do not (I add a \n)

```
my_string="esrhjg erguhg rziughrtPARTITIONED BY hz\nueirghf zreeuifh iuehg reuhg riutghSTORED ASiugh oer hfz"
p="(?<=PARTITIONED BY).*(?=STORED AS)"
str_replace(my_string,p,"TO REPLACE")
```

How to make str_replace work if the "between" string contains a linebreak \n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ICU regex flavor, used in all `stringr` functions, a dot matches any character *but a newline*.

You may use an inline `(?s)` modifier - `"(?s)(?<=PARTITIONED BY).*(?=STORED AS)"`:

```
my_string="esrhjg erguhg rziughrtPARTITIONED BY hz\nueirghf zreeuifh iuehg reuhg riutghSTORED ASiugh oer hfz"
p="(?s)(?<=PARTITIONED BY).*(?=STORED AS)"
str_replace(my_string,p,"TO REPLACE")
```

Note that you do not need this complex regex, actually, you may just use the TRE regex with `sub` where `.` matches a newline, too:

```
my_string = "esrhjg erguhg rziughrtPARTITIONED BY hzueirghf zreeuifh iuehg reuhg riutghSTORED ASiugh oer hfz"
sub("PARTITIONED BY.*STORED AS", "PARTITIONED BY -TO_REPLACE- STORED AS", my_string)
## or with backreferences:
sub("(PARTITIONED BY).*(STORED AS)", "\\1 -TO_REPLACE- \\2", my_string)
```

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/n7poj9).

If you have multiple substrings to replace in a string, you will need either `str_replace_all` or `gsub` with a pattern where `.*` is replaced with `.*?`.